# Conditional Expectation: How do you get the first line in this solution?

Tags: probability

I understand how you get from 1st to 2nd line but i don't get how the two terms are generated in the first line. I looked up Conditional Expectations but i still couldn't make sense of this.
Thank you.

[image: conditional expectation]

provenance...

[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]

Comment: What are the definitions of $A_{0}$ and $S(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the order of the items being equated is not the best for understanding. It might be better to follow as
$$
\mathrm{E}\{A_0\mid S(n)=1\}=\frac{\mathrm{P}\{A_0=1,S(n)=1\}}{\mathrm{P}\{S(n)=1\}}
$$
by the definition of conditional probability.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{P}\{A_0=1,S(n)=1\}}{\mathrm{P}\{S(n)=1\}}=\frac{\mathrm{E}\{A_0\cdot S(n)\}}{\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}
$$
which follows if $A_0$ and $S(n)$ are independent and take values in $\{0,1\}$.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{E}\{A_0\cdot S(n)\}}{\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}=\mathrm{E}\{A_0\}+\frac{\mathrm{E}\{A_0\cdot S(n)\}-\mathrm{E}\{A_0\}\cdot\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}{\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}
$$
which is, of course, simply algebra.

If your question was why the items were ordered as they are, I don't know. Perhaps the important equation that will be used later is
$$
\mathrm{E}\{A_0\mid S(n)=1\}=\mathrm{E}\{A_0\}+\frac{\mathrm{E}\{A_0\cdot S(n)\}-\mathrm{E}\{A_0\}\cdot\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}{\mathrm{E}\{S(n)\}}
$$
and so they wanted that to appear together.

Comment: that's what i was asking: why are the items ordered that way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb P(Y\in\{0,1\})=1$ and $X$ is integrable, then $\mathbb E(X\mid Y=1)=\mathbb E(XY)/\mathbb P(Y=1)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=1)=\mathbb E(Y)$ hence, for every real number $a$,
$$
\mathbb E(X\mid Y=1)=\frac{\mathbb E(X;Y=1)}{\mathbb P(Y=1)}=\frac{\mathbb E(XY)}{\mathbb E(Y)}=a+\frac{\mathbb E(XY)-a\cdot\mathbb E(Y)}{\mathbb E(Y)}.
$$
Apply this to $X=A_0$, $Y=S(n)$, and $a=E(A_0)$.

Comment: OK thanks. I still don't get it (sorry): The part i don't understand well enough (and maybe not expressing myself correctly) is how they are able to jump from E(X|Y=1) to a + [E(XY) - aE(Y)]/E(Y). You seem to get there by first going through the second line of their solution - which is what makes sense to me. (but how do you go the other way?)

Comment: I really do not know what you are asking... Anyway, you might start by noticing that the RHS of the identity in my answer does not depend on $a$.

Comment: That's fine. I got it now (just slow and thick-headed). What i was looking to understand (how they got first line from (4)) came from solving for lambda in (2) using (3). Thanks again.

Comment: If this was your question, I wonder what is the status of your first comment and I am sorry to say that you are spectacularly bad at asking questions.

Comment: Did - you have some growing to do.

Comment: This is what I call a proper appreciation of the time spent by others to help you.